# jQuery doesn't hide after uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem using jQuery code only on Firefox, that shows html details on checking a box that should disappears again while unchecking. The code is:

```
$('#gepaeck').on('click', function() {
  showGepaeckwert($(this));
});

function showGepaeckwert(t) {
  status = $(t).prop('checked');
  if (status) {
    $('.Gepaeck').show();
  } else {
    $('.Gepaeck').hide();
  }
}
```

On Chrome it works fine. Can somebody give me hint or help in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this `showGepaeckwert(this);`

Comment: no, it didn't help.

Comment: can you share also your HTML ?

Comment: `showGepaeckwert($(this));` change this to `showGepaeckwert(this);`? Did you try this?

Comment: use `this` instead of `$(this)` in `showGepaeckwert()` function

Comment: i changed and tried showGepaeckwert(this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### if `#gepaeck` is a checkbox (input) then:

```
$('#gepaeck').on('change', showGepaeckwert);

function showGepaeckwert(e) {
    $('.Gepaeck').toggle( this.checked );
}
```

---

jQuery [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method documentation:

> The second version of the method accepts a Boolean parameter. If this
>   parameter is true, then the matched elements are shown; if false, the
>   elements are hidden.

Comment: Thank you very much, that has helped!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .prop('checked') returns a string, not a boolean. There are a couple of ways to get around this.

Compare to string in the if:

```
if (status == 'true') {
  $('.Gepaeck').show();
}
```

Set the status var to a boolean dependent on the string value:

```
status = $(t).prop('checked') == 'true' ? true : false;
```

Personally, I would prefer the second way.

Answer (score 0):

The `click` event fires before `change` event, thus `checked` has not been updated

```
$('#gepaeck').on('change', showGepaeckwert).trigger('change');

function showGepaeckwert() {
    $('.Gepaeck').toggle(this.checked);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/terupalizi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact your `status` is not a `Boolean` but a `string`.

To convert string into `Bolean` use following condition

```
status = (status === 'true' || status === true) || false;
```

See working example:

```js
function showGepaeckwert(t) {
  var status = $(t).prop('checked');
  
  status = (status === 'true' || status === true) || false;
  
  if (status) {
    $('.Gepaeck').show();
  } else {
    $('.Gepaeck').hide();
  }
}
```

```css
.Gepaeck {
  padding: 20px;
  
  border: 1px solid;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Select me
<input type="checkbox" id="example1" checked onchange="showGepaeckwert('#' + this.id)" />

<br>

<div class="Gepaeck">
  Hide me
</div>
```